# Неразрешенная ссылка класса на самого себя

Tags: c++

Как такое понимать, и как решить?

```
class engine
{
public:
    static engine* get_engine(window** window);
    graphics* get_graphics();
    void draw_rectangle(D2D1_RECT_F** rectangle, ID2D1Brush** brush, bool fill = false, float stroke = 1) const;
    void draw_ellipse();
    void draw_text(std::wstring text);
    void resize(RECT rect);
    void release();
    void run();
private:
    explicit engine(window** wnd);
    ~engine();
    static engine* instance_;
    graphics* gfx_;
    window** window_;
};
```

```
engine* engine::get_engine(window** window)
{
    if (!instance_)
    {
        instance_ = new engine(window);
    }

    return instance_;
}
```

```
1>engine.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""private: static class base::controls::engine * base::controls::engine::instance_" (?instance_@engine@controls@base@@0PEAV123@EA)"
1>C:\Users\YieR\source\repos\proj\awgui\x64\Debug\awgui.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

Comment: У Вас проблема не в ссылке на себя, а в том, что Вы не определяете статическую переменную. Почитайте про то как это делается, информации море.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная ошибка, вернее, недоделка - кроме объявления

```
static engine* instance_;
```

нужно отдельно определение в .cpp-файле:

```
engine* engine::instance_;
```

Comment: А то что экземпляр находится в классе, это никак не создаст утечку памяти при удалении объекта?

Comment: В классе вы его только объявляете. И именно *в классе*. Он *один на все объекты*. Статический член создается в начале программы, уничтожается в конце. Если он у вас указатель - автоматического освобождения памяти не будет, но оно и не требуется в конце работы программы.

Comment: Хм, как я понимаю при таком раскладе в классе тогда вообще не обязательно объявлять данный указатель?

Comment: Можно и как внешний. Тут как вам удобнее, и чего именно вы хотите. Например, в классе он может быть закрытым, а как это сделать вне класса?

Comment: `Например, в классе он может быть закрытым, а как это сделать вне класса?` Понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили статическое поле, но не определили его. 
Определите его следующим образом

```
engine* engine::instance_ = nullptr
```

либо после определения класса в h файле, а лучше вынесите в cpp файл класса, где вы определяете методы класса